# Conditionally duplicating rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, parent-child

I have an Excel list of articles that needs to be converted into a parent-child list. Each article has either the same MPN, and/or the same name, only e.g. size or color are different.
The list looks like this:

```
MPN      name   size
1        foo    S
1        foo    M
1        foo    L
2        bar    S
2        bar    M
2        bar    XL
```

I insert cols ID and pID myself, in order to be able to achieve the following list:

```
ID pID  MPN      name   size
1       1        foo
2  1    1        foo    S    
3  1    1        foo    M
4  1    1        foo    L
5       2        bar
6  5    2        bar    S  
7  5    2        bar    M
8  5    2        bar    L
9  5    2        bar    XL
```

So, for all rows having the same MPN (or name), copy the first row above the block, and put the new row´s ID into the pID column of the following rows containing the same MPN.

The IDs are actually a string, so they don´t have to be sequential. If it´s easier to achieve, something like...

```
ID pID  MPN      name   size
1       1        foo  
1S 1    1        foo    S
1M 1    1        foo    M
1L 1    1        foo    L
```

... works for me as well, basically CONCATENATE() pID and size.

Can something like this be done with VBA?

Comment: If your question really is "*Can something like this be done with VBA?*" then the answer is "yes". But I assume that is not what you expected. But if you expect a more specific answer then you need to show what you already have tried (your code) and ask a more specific question to it, because no one can write the code for you. Also think about if Excel is the right tool because you might consider a real database.

Comment: Like @Peh said, it is doable with VBA but you have to try it first. As a starting point, have a look at `FOR` loops

Comment: Jup, might deserve this ;-) I actually have no clue about VBA, coming from the PHP world, and the only thing I´ve tried is filters and lookups. With lists 1000+ long... tiring :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ConditionallyDuplicateRows()
Dim lRw As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert

Range("A1").Value = "ID"
Range("B1").Value = "pID"
Range("C1").Value = "MPN"

lRw = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

For i = lRw To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i).Value <> Range("B" & i + 1).Value Then
       Range("B" & i).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
       'New MPN
       Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 1).Value = Range("B" & i + 2).Value
       'New Name
       Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 2).Value = Range("B" & i + 2).Offset(, 2).Value

       Range("B" & i).Offset(2, 1).Value = Range("B" & i).Offset(2).Value
    Else
        Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 1).Value = Range("B" & i + 1).Value
    End If
Next i

lRw = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A2:A" & lRw)
    .Formula = "=C2&E2"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: (1) I hardly recommend to use `Option Explicit` and declare **all** variables. (2) Also in a productive environment defined worksheets should be used for accessing `Range` and `Rows` etc, eg. like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")…` otherwise it might take the wrong worksheet.

Comment: Thanks! I tested it with some of our lists, but thanks to my poor example, there are some minor things I tried to figure out myself yesterday. I´m no VBA afficionado, so none of it worked ;-) The problems: first I need to copy the entire row, instead of populating single cells. Second, the MPN has to be different from ID/pID, more like a counter, ideally with an offset. And some manufacturers have the same MPNs even if the names are different (color as part of the name). Those would need to get their own ID (unique parent) as well.